# Combine two similar documents MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there any possible way to combine two documents in mongodb?

Imagine I have a collection with this documents:

```
{ "_id":ObjectId("142342432"), "name":"Chris", "surname":"Patrick", "pets":["dog", "cat"] }
{ "_id":ObjectId("142342752"), "name":"Chris", "surname":"Patrick", "pets":["lizard"] }
more than x2000 documents
```

And some other documentes. My idea would be to group each of the entries by name and surname and in case they match, join the `pets` array `$addToSet`.

The idea is to delete those two documents and add a new one with a new generated id and the combination. Deleting one document and appending the array to the other one, would also be ok.

My main problem is that I should be updating the collection, so it wouldn't be just a dump. And it can't be inefficient to dump it into a file and import it later on.

Thanks!

Update: Using mongodb 3.4

Comment: What mongod version are you using?

Comment: @StyvaneS. I'm using mongod 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can achieve this in a single query :

- first, unwind `pets` array
- then, group by `name` and `surname`, and combine arrays with **`$addToSet`**
- finally, write the output to the same collection using **`$out`**

**Be carefull, this will overwrite the original collection!**
before running this, you should create a dump of your current collection to avoid any data loss

here is the query:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([  
   { $unwind: {
       path: "$pets",
       preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
       }
   },
   {  
      $group:{  
         _id:{  
            name:"$name",
            surname:"$surname"
         },
         pets:{  
            $addToSet:"$pets"
         }, 
         otherField: {
            $first: "$otherField"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $out:"collectionName"
   }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, didn't know about the `$out` operator. Do you know  what should I do if I want to keep all the other fields of the document, taking the first occurrence?

Comment: @lpares12 yes use the **`$first`** operator, see my edit

Comment: Sure, thanks. Although I just realized that his won't work in cases where there are documents where `pets : []`, since doing `$unwind` will ignore them.

Comment: @lpares12 juste set `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` property of **`$unwind`** stage to **true** to keep them, see the edit